# Building DialogFragment with partially static and dynamic layout

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog, dialogfragment

I want to build a `DialogFragment` that looks like this:

1. it has a spinner/drop-down menu in the top part of the content area that allows user to select a state
2. the layout below (1) changes depending on the state
3. the positive button of the dialog does different things depending on the state and the values the user select using the widgets in (2)
4. (1) is the fixed part; it is always there.

Should I use a single `DialogFragment` and swap layouts? Or should I just build multiple `DialogFragment`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a single DialogFragment, and for the layout under (1) use a FrameLayout containing the possible states, and change the visibility on change of (1), or a ViewSwitcher depending on your favour.

Comment: If I use different dialogs/dialog fragments, how will the transition look like when the user chooses a different state? Will there be popping out and popping up of dialogs? Btw, I am also from HK!

Comment: Hello HKer, really sorry for overlooked and thought it is about something else. (You know it is time to back home now :P), updated my answer. Really sorry for my previous answer.

Comment: So it's either changing the visibility or using a view switcher. Thanks!